# How to create a GWT anchor with an ignored href?

Tags: java, gwt, onclick, anchor

Let's say I have HTML anchor like so:

```
<a id="myid" href="something?a=b">Link</a>
```

and I want to wrap this in a GWT Anchor that has a click handler that sends the user somewhere else and ignores the href value.

in regular javascript it seems like you can accomplish this by doing:

```
<a id="myid" href="something?a=b" onclick="goSomewhereElse(); return false;">Link</a>
```

But in GWT there doesn't appear to be a way to do it ... am i missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can you just use the g:Anchor tag instead of a?

```
<g:Anchor ui:field="myLink1">The Link To Click</g:Anchor>
```

And then in your implementation of the file you could have something like...

```
@UiField
protected Anchor myLink1;

@UiHandler("myLink1")
public void handleMyLink1Click(ClickEvent event)
{
    //code to execute on click;
    event.preventDefault(); //If you want the href present
}
```

This would eliminate the need to have the href present at all.  Also, if you need to have the href present, since you have the clickEvent you could add event.preventDefault() to the UiHandler.  (as seen on the second line in the UiHandler)

Maybe I completely missed what you were going for, but I hope this helps a little!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Anchor`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) and add a `ClickHandler` to it.

Comment: I added a click handler, but the browser still sends the user to whatever the value in "href" is.  This is because the onClick function has a "void" return type so there is no way to tell the browser to ignore the href value as far as i can tell.

Comment: Try with event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Anchor` as `new Anchor(textToDisplay)` and add a `ClickHandler` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
<a id="myid" href="javascript:;">Link</a>
```